# Is there a way to hide just the prop type errors that come in developer console - not all the errors

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

As part of a really large React codebase, we have added a lot of prop type check over the years.

They output a lot of errors when prop type validations fail:

[image]

I noticed that in the developer console, I can override the default settings to hide all the errors like below:

[image]

and if I do that all the normal errors and these type invalidation errors get hidden.

Is there a way I can hide only the prop-type check errors (by classifying them as some other output type) and keep getting the usual JS errors - to reduce the noise I'm getting and this also causes a lot of vertical scroll which is hard to keep up with and causes the usual console messages to lose sight of.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer please mark the answer as solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Solution**

you can use filter field provided in developer console

[image]

you can filter out error based on their content using regex, simply write `-/Failed\s+prop\s+type/` in the filter field.

### **Explanation**

we write regex in between `//` , we append it with `-` to indicate that don't show anything that matches the regex, `\s+` is used to represent whitespace in regex.